# Как при нажатии кнопки в tkinter выводить случайный элемент из списка (без циклов) Python?

Tags: python, функции, tkinter, случайные-числа

**Цель:** сделать рандомайзер который при нажатии кнопки будет выводить случайную фразу из массива `A`, (по типу игры "правда или действие), но с одной кнопкой.
Что писать после строки `def cliked():` ?

[image: Код]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: на этом ресурсе скриншоты с экрана не приветствуются, только фото рукописного текста на холсте

Answer (score 0):

Вывод случайной фразы из списка `A` в консоль:

```
print(random.choice(A))
```

ИЛИ

Замена текста виджета `lbl` на случайную фразу из списка `A`:

```
lbl.configure(text=random.choice(A))
```